# How set a custom directory for pages in Next JS? (not src or root)

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm encountering a problem when set a custom directory in Next JS.

I know that by default, the pages directory should be in root or the src directory, but this option doesn't suit me because I can't hide all the frontend files in one directory.

Instead i want to do it this way:

```
src
├── frontend
│   ├── pages
│   │   ├── index.tsx                         
│   │   ├── firstPage.tsx                     
│   │   ├── ...
│   │   components
│   │   ├── ...                   
├── backend
│   ├── ...
```

However Next JS doesn't allow me to do this and I don't understand why, I've tried looking for possibilities for this, e.g:

```
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "next ./src/frontend",
  },
```

This works, but it's still not what I need.  With this approach, next creates tsconfig, .next, etc directly in the frontend directory, which looks weird, I would like to keep the configuration files in the root directory.

It seems that for some reason I can't have pages directory inside frontend directory, but I can't figure out what this has to do with. If this is really the case could you tell me why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems Next.js officially supports only `./pages` or `./src/pages` directories. Tim explains his point of view over this decision in his comment in one of many issues requesting this option on Github [see](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/4315#issuecomment-522263598). More can be found also [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/4315) and [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/8451).

However, you might want to check out this [discussion](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/23640), as Daniel's fork has option to look for pages in additiona directories.

Answer (score -1):

We cannot set custom pages in next.js , but after some research i found the way to change which folder should act as pages/ ,

Like for example if i have multiple apps like , cars/ , bikes/ , we cannot make next.js to choose the cars/ or bikes/ , but i am making which folder should act as pages/

So here is the steps

**setup below gulp devDependencies in your project**

```
"gulp": "^4.0.2",
"gulp-clean": "^0.4.0",
"gulp-fs": "^0.0.2",
"gulp-rename": "^2.0.0",
```

**Create gulpfile.js with following content**

```
const gulp = require('gulp')
const fs = require('fs')
var clean = require('gulp-clean')
gulp.task('clean-pages', function () {
  return gulp.src('pages/', { read: false }).pipe(clean())
})
gulp.task('eject-pages', function () {
  return gulp.src('./pages/**/*.{js,tsx,ts,scss}').pipe(gulp.dest('./simba'))
})
gulp.task('serve-cars', function () {
  return gulp.src('./cars/**/*.{js,tsx,ts,scss}').pipe(gulp.dest('./pages'))
})
gulp.task('serve-bikes', function () {
  return gulp.src('./bikes/**/*.{js,tsx,ts,scss}').pipe(gulp.dest('./pages'))
})
gulp.task('bikes', gulp.series('eject-pages', 'clean-pages', 'serve-bikes'))
gulp.task('cars', gulp.series('clean-pages', 'serve-cars'))
```

it will replace which the pages folder with cars or bikes

**in package.json add scripts**

```
"build-cars": "gulp cars && next build",
"build-bikes": "gulp bikes && next build",
```